# Game problems that machine learning won't solve better than humans

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, games

Is there any type of game that could not be beaten by machine learning algorithm? Checkers and chess is not a problem for computers, go also.. But is there a class of problems in terms of let's say 'games' where people are still (and probably will be in the future) better than computers.

---

To sum up:
Is it possible to create a board game with fairly simple rules but hard to masterize for machine so that people playing such game would perform way better than computers?

Comment: What do you mean by " Checkers and chess is not a problem for computers, go also.." ? Computers out-perform humans in all of these games.

Comment: In general, reinforcement learning is not successful when the space of possible actions is enormous and there is a long-term lag between initial decisions and outcomes.

Comment: I am not an expert with GO but as far as I know the space of possible actions so I guess the case of outcomes is the weak point of that game. I will rewrite a bit my main question.